# Validate JSON in Python 3.6 where number of inner blob is variable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON, which I need to validate if it is in the right format, before storing. I saw the jsonschema package and questions in SO related to it, but in my case, there can be any number of inner content in the list 'Data' which is also the root. How should my code be, to do the needful? Below code block gives a 'pass' to the wrong data (improper structure) too:

```
json_document = '''{
  "Data": [
    {
      "vol_no": "001",
      "loc": "2341",
      "ts": "2016-02-04 14:25:19.000000"
    },
    {
      "vol_no": "023",
      "loc": "4635",
      "ts": "2016-02-02 01:14:38.000000"
    }
    ]
}'''



schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "vol_no": {"type": "string"},
        "loc": {"type": "number"},
        "ts": {"type": "string"}
    },
}

for idx, item in enumerate((json.loads(json_document))['Data']):
    try:
        print(item)
        print(schema)
        validate(item, schema)
        print("Record #{}: OK\n".format(idx))
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
        print("Record #{}: ERROR\n".format(idx))
        print(str(ve) + "\n")
```

Improper structure example. I changed key name of first element and removed ts from second element of the array in JSON, but it too doesn't error out:

```
json_document = '''{
  "Data": [
    {
      "abcdsddfwq": "001",
      "loc": "2341",
      "ts": "2016-02-04 14:25:19.000000"
    },
    {
      "vol_no": "023",
      "loc": "4635"
    }
    ]
}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell that data must be an array where all items are objects with some required properties:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "vol_no": "string",
            "loc": "string",
            "ts": "string"
        },
        "required": ["vol_no", "loc", "ts"]
    }
}
```

Comment: And what should be the code to validate this? Kindly help!

Comment: I've updated the code block above, even the updated one fails, cannot use yours as I've to have the validator logic. As, if I'm using your schema and the running validate as is, it fails.

Comment: @AakashBasu: if you need to do the loop yourself just use as schema the object part... i.e. `{"type": "object", "properties":{ ...}, "required":[...]}`.